# Is it possible to pass through commandline parameters to the "execute launcher" action?

Tags: install4j

Today I have a question to the update application. I want to execute my application launcher and pass throught all commandline parameters, which I have given to the updater application like the following code:

```
C:\temp\MyApplication\updater.exe -param1 1234 -param2 qwer
```

This should be start the application launcher like that:

```
C:\temp\MyApplication\application.exe -param1 1234 -param2 qwer
```

Therefore I tried to use the argument property in the execution action but I do not find out yet how to recieve the commandline parameters to pass through to the launcher. May that be possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get command line parameters with

```
context.getExtraCommandLineArguments()
```

All command line parameters that are interpreted by install4j are removed from that list.

Comment: Thank you. That's the solution I searched for. Now I fill an installer variable and set this one to the "execute launcher" action. Works fine.

Comment: Is there also the possibility to pass through the installer parameter as well? Like -Vmyparam=xyz should also be given to the application launcher (or maybe another bundle installation medium)

Comment: No, you would have to generate these arguments yourself.